# Tomcat clustering on window machine

Tags: apache, tomcat, cluster-computing

Hi I am setting up a Tomcat cluster on windows machine with Apache httpd server.

I am done with two steps - load balancing and session affinity and now i am at 3rd step.Session Replication.In that step I need to add multicast route first.

In tutorial command of adding route in linux environment is given.

```
sudo route add -net224.0.0.0 netmask 240.0.0.0 dev eth0
```

here eth0 is device.

But,I am not getting how to add this in Windows 10. I am finding it out and trying on my machine. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have set up the tomcat cluster on window machine using Tomcat 8.For Windows environment no need to run above command.It is working fine absolutely without this command.In almost all blogs present over web,use linux and given above command to setup route but in windows it is not required.But still question one question is pending why it is not require ?